# How do I distribute more weight to higher index

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

Given the following example, how can I distribute more volume/weight to higher indexes? Almost like the opposite of FIFO. One potential solution would be to simply reverse the array once an algorithm has been applied, although would like to avoid that if possible.

To get me headed in the right direction, I need to apply some algorithm / mathematical formula to find out how much volume out of the total available volume I can give each index, depending upon it's weight by index.

```
Total available volume: 150
Output: (volume not accurate but to exemplify the output)

1 - 20 volume
2 - 30 volume
3 - 40 volume
4 - 60 volume
```

Comment: total_volume*partial_weight/total_weight, where total_weight=sum(partial_weight) ?

Comment: You need to post some code for people to make it reasonable for people to help you out.

Comment: Does each index have a weight as specified by some condition/array? Or is it equal to the index itself?

Comment: You need significantly more specification.  An answer to Abhinav's question is a good start.  But also, is the number of indices fixed?  Is there a minimum amount per index?  Is there a minimum difference between indices?  Does each value have to be an integer?  There's simply not enough to go on here.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur each index has a weight equal to the index itself.

Comment: @ScottSauyet in my experience, the absence of something is evidence that it's not required. There are no minimum differences, each value does not need to be an integer - it can indeed be a float, etc.

Comment: @LeviRoberts, then is there anything wrong with this as an answer?: `const apportionVolume = (v) => [1, 2, 3, 4]`?  If so, what's wrong with it according to the specification above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the volume difference `dV` between consequent indexes `i` is constant and starting volume is `V0` then you can do this:

let `V` be "FIFO" volume, `i` the index and `V(i)` its volume so:

```
V = V(1) + V(2) + ... + V(n)
V(i) = V(i-1)+dV
V(1) = V0
-----------------------------
V = V0 + V0+dV + V0+dV+dV + ... + V0 + (n-1)*dV
V = n*V0 + dV*(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1)
V - n*V0 = dV*(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1)
dV = (V - n*V0) / (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1)
```

so compute the sum of series `1+2+3+...n-1` and compute the final `dV`

You examle:

```
V  = 150
V0 =  20
n  =   6
dV = (V - n*V0) / (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1)
dV = (150 - 6*20) / (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 5)
dV = 30 / (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)
dV = 30 / 15
dV = 2
```

so:

```
i V(i) sum
1 20    20
2 22    42
3 24    66
4 26    92
5 28   120
6 30   150
```

Comment: But is the `20` an input or is it derived?  For instance if `V = 180`, and `n = 6`, we might well have `[10, 18, 26, 34, 42, 50]`.  And the same is true for `n`.  Is it an input or is it derived?  So if we had `V = 100`, and `V0 = 20`, we might well have `[20, 21, 22, 37]` and `n = 4`,  I think the problems is far too underspecified.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes I agree its not clearly stated this however should work in both cases ... if OP want a derived `V0` it can easily be equal `dV` or some fraction of `V` based on `n` there are infinite possibilities that is why I focused on dV which is straightforward in case of constant increase like in example

Comment: Apologies for not being able to be clearer. I'm new to mathematical algorithms. I'm primarily a software engineer, with little experience doing calculations. I believe your solution will work and get me headed in the right direction. Let me digest the information for a bit and if I conclude that it's sufficient will reward you with the accepted answer. Thank you for taking a swing at this!

Comment: @LeviRoberts btw the sum `1+2+3+...+n` is a well known series so there is an `O(1)` [formula for it](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-arithmetic.html) ... so: `(1+2+3+...+n) = n*(n+1)/2`

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified any proportion or constraint on the distribution, there might be a simple solution.
For indexes `1,2,3,4,...` assign volume `x,2x,3x,4x...`. So sum of all volumes becomes `x+2x+3x+....+nx` = `((n*(n+1))/2) * x`.
Let total volume be `V`. Using the above formula, we get `x = (2*V)/(n*(n+1))`. Now you can just assign `x,2x,3x...` as discussed.